# Tkinter Canvas Flicker

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm drawing small black and white video frames to a Tkinter canvas using this code (at 10Hz)

```
self.image.buf = bytearray(header.width * header.height);
self.image.buf[:] = image
self.image.im = Image.frombuffer("L", (header.width, header.height), self.image.buf).resize((320, 240)).transpose(Image.ROTATE_180)
self.image.tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image.im)
if (self.image.id): self.image.delete(self.image.id);
self.image.id = self.image.create_image((0, 0), image=self.image.tkimage, anchor=NW)
```

Everytime a frame gets drawn, the widget flickers. Isn't the Tk canvas supposed to be double buffered? what can I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So i figured out the problem -- it seems you have to create your tkimage from the same thread that tk is running in or bad things happen. Thanks to anyone who looked at this!

Comment: You should probably mark your own answer as the accepted answer so that the solution is clear to anyone who comes along later.

Comment: I will when i Can -- StackOverflow mandates a 24 hour waiting period.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's enough detail in your question to say for certain what the problem is. It's possible to swap images in and out without flicker and your code doesn't look too unusual, so there may be something else in your code that is causing the problem.

Here's one thing to try: instead of deleting and re-creating the canvas item each iteration, try using one canvas item that you reconfigure to use the new image using the `itemconfig` method.

For example:

```
if self.image.id is None:
    self.image.id = self.image.create_image(...)
else:
    self.image.itemconfig(self.image.id, image=self.image.tkimage)
```

Also, if you're not using the canvas for anything else you might want to consider using a label widget rather than a canvas and an image item.

Comment: Hm...i've changed my code to use itemconfig, which seems more correct. The image still flickers, however.

Comment: I also tried using a label, which is a little simpler, and it *still* flickers